# CSS Border - How to make a subtract border?

Tags: css, border

im trying to create this kind of border, is there a way to do it with css? thanks for the help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1PkW.png)

i have no idea how to even search for this...

Comment: Probably the easiest approach is to have a div, with a border, and then set that div's position as relative. Then put 1 or more divs within that div positioned absolute and size them and position them to cover up parts of the border as shown above. Then put the div content on a higher z-level than those divs that cover part of the border

Comment: Guys i made it , here is the code if anyone needs it 

.border-one:after{
    content: "";
    border-top: 7px solid #1E1E1E;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -22px;
    left: 183px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.border-one:before{
     content: "";
    border-left: 7px solid #1E1E1E;
    height: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px;
    left: -9px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 99999;
}

Comment: Don't hesitate to make your own answer instead of posting a comment so it will help other people more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example using [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 40%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: '';
  background: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 1px;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest approach is to have a div, with a border, and then set that div's position as relative. Then put 1 or more divs within that div positioned absolute and size them and position them to cover up parts of the border as shown above. Then put the div content on a higher z-level than those divs that cover part of the border

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.block1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  top: -2px;
  left: 10%;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 2px;
  height: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  top: 5%;
  left: -2px;
}

.content {
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
  
    <div class="block1"></div>
    <div class="block2"></div>
    
    <div class="content">
      <h1>Something</h1>
      <h3>random text<h3>
      <hr>
      <h3>random text<h3>
      <hr>
      <h3>random text<h3>
      <hr>
      <h3>random text<h3>
      <hr>
      <h3>random text<h3>
      <hr>
      <h3>random text<h3>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Just mess around with the top and left values for the block1 and block2 classes to get the effect you would like

Comment: For some reason it doesn't display the snippet preview right, so just click the full page link in the top right of the preview window

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I did and it works - also with pseudo elements
Thank you all for your answers!

```
.border-one:after{
content: "";
border-top: 7px solid #1B1B1B;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
top: -22px;
left: 183px;
margin: 20px;
display: block;
z-index: 99999;}

.border-one:before{
 content: "";
border-left: 7px solid #1B1B1B;
height: 140px;
position: absolute;
top: 72px;
left: -9px;
margin: 20px;
display: block;
z-index: 99999;}
```